# Applying bootstrap grid on tablet screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a small web project and I want to display three navigation images using bootstrap classes on a tablet screen. My first navigation image needs to display first in full width and the other two navigation images display below the first one side by side. It works fine on medium and large screen. Need some help. Below is my code and the images of the result to be achieved.

[Image on medium and Large screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUkV2.png) [Image on Tablet screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuYi1.png). It needs to stack on smartphone screen.

```
<div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="left">
        <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" id="side1">
            <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        </nav>  
        <nav class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" id="side2">
            <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        </nav>    
    </div>
    </nav> 
  </div>
```

Comment: what is id="left",side1 and side2 ... any css for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="left" style="background-color:red; height:100px;">          
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="side1" style="background-color:pink; height:100px;">
        </nav>  
        <nav class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="side2" style="background-color:tan; height:100px;">          
        </nav>    
      </div>
    </nav> 
  </div>    
</div>
```

Make sure you use col-md-6 instead of col-md-2 in the second row

Comment: or just use .col-sm-6 and get rid of .col-md-6 altogether.

Comment: I put the code here: https://jsbin.com/yirixuc/edit?html,output
What exactly is not working?